# Why the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution curve is peaked at $u=0$?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

[image: Please refer to the following picture]

Can the reason be that most particles are at rest.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289688/154997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is the probability distribution for a *single* velocity component (e.g. $u_x$), not the overall speed ($u = \sqrt{u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2}$).  You can work out the probability distribution for the speed, and (in 3D) it looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%204%2Fsqrt(pi)*u%5E2%20e%5E(-u%5E2)%20from%200%20to%204):
$$ f(u) = 4\pi \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k T}\right)^{3/2} u^2 e^{-\frac{m u^2}{2kT}}$$
[image]

So as you can see, although the peak for a given component of the velocity is centered at zero, the peak for the overall speed is not.

If you have a billion particles all moving in different directions but with the same speed $u$, their velocities all lie on the surface of a sphere of radius $u$ in velocity space.  In other words, their velocity vectors are all the same length, but they point in different directions.  Assuming that there is no preferred direction in the gas, then *all of these points are equally likely*.

On the other hand, the collection of points whose x-component is near zero lie in the $u_x=0$ plane.  I've plotted the intersection of the sphere and the plane here:

[image]

Do you see how large that blue circle is?  The circumference of the circle is proportional to the number of points which have $u=\sqrt{u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2}$ **and** $u_x \approx 0$.

Look what happens when I increase $u_x$ to $0.5 u$:

[image]

and now to $0.9 u$:

[image]

As I move away from $u_x=0$, the circles get smaller.  The smaller the circles, the smaller the number of points that satisfy the given arrangement, so the less likely the arrangement is to occur.

Answer (score 1):

The equation and graph you show isn't what we normally call the [Maxwell Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). It's the velocity distribution rather than the speed distribution.

When we talk about the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution we normally mean the probability that the speed, i.e. the modulus of the velocity, has a value between $u$ and $u+du$, and this gives us the distribution:

$$ f(u) = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k T}\right)^{3/2} 4\pi u^2 e^{-mu^2/2kT} \tag{1} $$

And this gives us curves that are zero at $v=0$ and $v\to\infty$ and peak at $v = \sqrt{2kT/m}$:

[image: MB distribution]

([image from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MaxwellBoltzmann-en.svg))

But suppose we ask a slightly different question. Suppose instead of looking at the modulus of the speed we ask for the distribution of the $x$ component of the velocity. Because the gas is overall stationary we expect there to be as many particles with positive $v_x$ as with negative $v_x$ i.e. the distribution of $v_x$ will be symmetric about $v_x=0$.

And this is what the graph you show gives you. It gives the probability distribution for $v_x$ (or $v_y$ or $v_z$):

$$ f(v_x) = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k T}\right)^{1/2} e^{-mv_x{}^2/2kT} \tag{2} $$

We get the speed distribution from equation (2) by noting that:

$$ u = |\mathbf v| = \sqrt{v_x{}^2 + v_y{}^2 + v_z{}^2} $$

And we have to multiply by a factor of $4\pi u^2$ because the volume of the spherical shell of velocities between $u$ and $u+du$ is $4\pi u^2 du$.

Or looking at this a different way, although the graph of $f(v_x)$ peaks at $v_x=0$ the particles that have $v_x=0$ can have any (non-zero) value of $v_y$ and $v_z$. So just because a particle has $v_x=0$ that doesn't mean its speed is zero.

Answer (score 0):

No. It just means the particles are moving perpendicular to the 1-dimension you have chosen for your distribution.

On the other hand, it may mean that there is no phase space there--the volume of a spherical shell of radius $u$ is $u^2du$, which is $0$ at $u=0$.